# Closedness of trajectories of an area-preserving flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to prove the following:

If $f:R^{2} \to R^{2}$ is a vector field in $C^{1}$ with no zeros, such that the flow $\Phi_{t}$ generated by $f$ preserves area (if $S$ is any open set, the area of $\Phi_{t}(S)$ is independent of $t$) then every trajectory is a closed set.

It is supposed to be an application of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem. But I just don't see how it is related, nor do I have come up with any ideas on how to solve it. I would appreciate any suggestions that can help me get started.

Thank you

Comment: So a translation is not a counterexample, if "closed" means closed set.

Comment: I'm thinking that since $f$ has no equilibrium points, every trajectory is a curve that divides $R^2$ into two positively invariant open sets, which makes it (the trajectory) closed, I don't see how the area preserving flow helps. I'm stuck with this too :(